# Create biggest possible rectangular polygon from grids in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, vector-grid, rectangle

I am working in QGIS (Modeler with some Python scripting) and I have troubles performing the following task:

I have the following grid:
[image: Original set of grids]

I have to create the biggest possible rectangle polygon out of this grid.

I am trying to find a way of selecting a set of grids so they'll create a rectangular polygon.

I thought about creating multiple polygons and finally compare them and keep the largest one.
[image: Possible polygons]

After the comparison keep the biggest polygon and have the following result (the polygon #3 in this case):
[image: Desired result]

Any suggestions?

Edit 1:
I tried the solution recommended by Louis Cottereau, but I got the following result:
[image]
I switched the coord_inititial values and the +, - signs, but I had the same results.

Comment: These look promising:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58892045/get-max-rectangle-area-from-numpy-array  or  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44427012/find-the-biggest-square-in-numpy-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two steps process:

1. use "minimum bounding geometry" processing algorithm to create a minimum oriented rectangle
   [image]
2. run the following python script you need to have two layers "Grid" with you small rectangles and "Bounding geometry" the result of step 1:

```python
import numpy as np

# Load layers
# Small rectangles
layer_grid = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Grid")[0] 
# Bounding box
layer_bounding_box = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Bounding geometry")[0]

# Calculate total grid bounding box length and height
feat_bbox = next(layer_bounding_box.getFeatures(), None)
geom_bbox = feat_bbox.geometry()
list_pt_bbox = geom_bbox.asPolygon()[0]
vector_length_bbox = list_pt_bbox[0] - list_pt_bbox[1]
vector_height_bbox = list_pt_bbox[1] - list_pt_bbox[2]
if vector_length_bbox.length() < vector_height_bbox.length():
    vector_length_bbox, vector_height_bbox = vector_height_bbox, vector_length_bbox

# Calculate grid rectangle length and height
list_rect_grid = list(layer_grid.getFeatures())
geom_rect = list_rect_grid[0].geometry()
list_pt_rect = geom_rect.asPolygon()[0]
vector_length_rect = list_pt_rect[0] - list_pt_rect[1]
vector_height_rect = list_pt_rect[1] - list_pt_rect[2]
if vector_length_rect.length() < vector_height_rect.length():
    vector_length_rect, vector_height_rect = vector_height_rect, vector_length_rect

# Calculate number of columns and rows
matrix_columns = round(vector_length_bbox.length() / vector_length_rect.length())
matrix_rows = round(vector_height_bbox.length() / vector_height_rect.length())

# Calculate normalized vectors for length and height
v_norm_length = vector_length_bbox / matrix_columns
v_norm_height = vector_height_bbox / matrix_rows
pt_origin = list_pt_bbox[0]

# Creation of matrix of 1's and 0's
# 1 meaning the position in the matrix corresponds to an existing grid rectangle
# 0 meaning the position in the matrix corresponds to an empty space
bool_matrix = [[0 for _ in range(matrix_rows)] for _ in range(matrix_columns)]
for rect in list_rect_grid:
    geom_rect = rect.geometry().buffer(0.000000001, 5)
    geom_rect_eng = QgsGeometry.createGeometryEngine(geom_rect.constGet())
    geom_rect_eng.prepareGeometry()
    for i in range(matrix_columns):
        for j in range(matrix_rows):
            # ps : might have to switch coord_initial[0<->1] and the - <-> + signs depending 
            # where the origin of your rectangle / boudingbox rectangle are
            first_pt = pt_origin - (v_norm_length * i) - (v_norm_height * j)
            second_pt = first_pt - v_norm_length
            third_pt = second_pt - v_norm_height
            fourth_pt = first_pt - v_norm_height
            temp_rect_list_pt = [
                first_pt, second_pt, third_pt, fourth_pt, first_pt
            ]
            geom = QgsGeometry().fromPolygonXY([temp_rect_list_pt])
            
            if geom_rect_eng.contains(geom.constGet()):
                bool_matrix[i][j] = 1
                break
        if bool_matrix[i][j]:
            break


#  source: https://www.andrewgclark.info/posts/2020-05-02_rectangle_algorithm/
def find_largest_rectangle_2D(array):
    """Gets the coordinates of the largest rectangle of 1s in a 2D binary array"""

    #first get the sums of successive vertical pixels
    vert_sums = (np.zeros_like(array)).astype('float')
    vert_sums[0] = array[0]
    for i in range(1,len(array)):
        vert_sums[i] = (vert_sums[i-1] + array[i]) * array[i]

    #declare some variables for keeping track of the largest rectangle
    max_area = -1
    pos_at_max_area = (0,0)
    height_at_max_area = -1
    x_end = 0

    #go through each row of vertical sums and find the largest rectangle
    for i in range(len(vert_sums)):
        positions = []  # a stack
        heights = []  # a stack
        for j in range(len(vert_sums[i])):
            h = vert_sums[i][j]
            if len(positions)==0 or h > heights[-1]:
                heights.append(h)
                positions.append(j)
            elif h < heights[-1]:
                while len(heights) > 0 and h < heights[-1]:
                    h_tmp = heights.pop(-1)
                    pos_tmp = positions.pop(-1)
                    area_tmp = h_tmp * (j - pos_tmp)
                    if area_tmp > max_area:
                        max_area = area_tmp
                        pos_at_max_area = (pos_tmp,i) #this is the bottom left
                        height_at_max_area = h_tmp
                        x_end = j
                heights.append(h)
                positions.append(pos_tmp)
        while len(heights) > 0:
            h_tmp = heights.pop(-1)
            pos_tmp = positions.pop(-1)
            area_tmp = h_tmp * (j - pos_tmp)
            if area_tmp > max_area:
                max_area = area_tmp
                pos_at_max_area = (pos_tmp,i) #this is the bottom left
                height_at_max_area = h_tmp
                x_end = j

    top_left = (int(pos_at_max_area[0]),int(pos_at_max_area[1] - height_at_max_area) + 1)
    width = int(x_end - pos_at_max_area[0])
    height = int(height_at_max_area - 1)

    return top_left,width,height   

# Algorithm to find the largest rectangle of 1's in a 2 dimension matrix
# of 1's and 0's
coord_initial, height, length = find_largest_rectangle_2D(np.array(bool_matrix))


# Convert origin coordinate and dimensions back to resulting polygon
# ps : might have to switch coord_initial[0<->1] and the - <-> + signs depending 
# where the origin of your rectangle / boudingbox rectangle are
first_pt = pt_origin - (v_norm_length * coord_initial[1]) - (v_norm_height * coord_initial[0])
second_pt = first_pt - v_norm_length * (length+1)
third_pt = second_pt - v_norm_height * (height+1)
fourth_pt = first_pt - v_norm_height * (height+1)
final_rect_list_pt = [
    first_pt, second_pt, third_pt, fourth_pt, first_pt
]
final_rect = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([final_rect_list_pt])
print(final_rect.asWkt())
```

result:
[image]
[image]

**PS: Depending on the orientation of the grid rectangles and bounding box rectangle (the origin of the polygon is top-left or top-right or bottom-right or ... and the points are clockwise or anticlockwise) you might have to modify  some operations as stated in the python script**

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive solution, your result is exactly what I am looking for.
However when I'm running the python script, I am getting an inadequate result, as shown  in my Edit 1.

Comment: Hum strange, are the results from `find_largest_rectangle_2D` correct? Do you know what step in the script seems to be the issue?

Comment: sorry for the late respone, but it seems that my problem is coming before the result from `find_largest_rectangle_2D`. I have issues with `bool_matrix`. The matrix is not generated correctly, as there are **0** where should be **1**.

Comment: the 4 points of the polygons (`first_pt` , `second_pt`, ...) might be wrongly created (depending on orientation of the rectangles) during the creation of the boolean matrix, you should print the geometries to make sure that for coords `i`, `j` the actual geometry matches the existing rectangle, if it doesn't it means you have to change the point origin and/or the -/+ that build the polygon rectangle, as stated in the comments there.

Comment: It seems that the problem is indeed related to the point origin and/or the -/+ that build the polygon rectangle. Thank you very much for your help, your method helped me a lot.